# How do i clear the datasnapshot so that i can re-enter the correct credentials after entering the wrong one

Tags: java, android-studio

When we login to the app and enter the wrong credentials for the username and password a "Login failed" toast will be shown but when we want to re-enter the correct credentials it will still show the login fail.

We use Firebase database to store the users and use it to match if its the correct user has login 
and use the Android studio IDE to code.

```
private void userlogin(final String username ,final String password) {
    users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.child(username).exists()){
                if(!username.isEmpty()){
                    User login=dataSnapshot.child(username).getValue(User.class);
                    if(login.getPassword().equals(password)){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully login",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Login failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User does not exists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You really should look into this document regarding Firebase authentication. https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/start/?gclid=CjwKCAiA8bnUBRA-EiwAc0hZkyCw7_gXNP9oQaiuudfrpeTjjsQ2HrbA-qwsNWIn-GbMZYp5F8-nhhoCUSYQAvD_BwE

Comment: We do not use the Firebase authentication method for this

Comment: but instead we use the firebase database datasnapshot, did try that link but it didn't work too